# Создание кастомного стиля окна со стандартным поведением

Tags: c#, wpf, .net

Чтобы убрать стандартную рамку окна установим свойство `Window.WindowStyle` как `None`. Получим такое окно:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мы видим 1-пиксельную серую рамку, белую (фоновый цвет окна, как полагаю) полоску сверху и тень. Размеры окна можно изменять, а рамка изменения размера располагается за пределами видимой рамки окна (за исключением верхней границы, которая, как решила Microsoft, должна находится именно в пределах видимой рамки - не на тени).

Именно эту верхнюю границу я и хотел бы сделать невидимой, оставляя возможность для изменения размера окна сверху. Меня бы удовлетворило решение, позволяющее размещать мои собственные кнопки просто поверх этой рамки с краю.

Можно сделать окно `AllowsTransparency`, но тогда пропадёт тень, рамка изменения размера окна (по видимому пропадает вся неклиентская область, и окно полностью в нашем распоряжении) и анимации сворачивания/разворачивания. Можно, конечно, попробовать сделать это всё самому: создать собственную рамку изменения размера окна просто с помощью каких нибудь элементов (например, `Rectangle`), нарисовать тень под нею, забить на анимации сворачивания/разворачивания.

Но возникает очень неприятный эффект - окно сильно дёргается при изменении его размера за такую нестандартную рамку. Т.е. обычный вызов `SetWindowPos` для `AllowsTransparency` окна приводит к таким проблемам. Использование флага `SWP_NOCOPYBITS` проблему не решает (это значит не нужно предлагать создавать обработчик на `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING` (и на `WM_NCCALCSIZE`, на сколько знаю, аналогично) и что там делать). Обычно такое поведение связано с тем, что выданная приложению временная квота для обновления содержимого окна просто истекает, и сама Windows копирует то, что есть в верхний левый угол, а остальное пространство окна заполняет фоновым цветом (далее приложение само должно "догонять"). На Windows 7 с отключённым Aero проблема остаётся.

Значит вопрос в том, как разместить пользовательские элементы задевая стандартную рамку изменения размера окна сверху, либо устранить эффект от вызова `SetWindowPos` для такого стиля окна.

Почему `WindowChrome` не подходит: да, с использованием этого `WindowChrome` дёргание действительно пропадает, но при условии, что `GlassFrameThickness` не 0 и `NonClientFrameEdges` не `None`. Последнее добавляет такую же полоску с указываемой стороны. `AllowsTransparency` нельзя применять вместе с такими значениями свойств (у меня просто окно не разворачивалось с панели задач).

Проект строится под .NET 4.5.

Comment: Мне кажется вы гонитесь за призраком, да, в WPF есть косяки в этом плане, но не на знаю, я всю "жизнь программиста" делал проекты с кастомными окнами, переписывая полностью интерфейс сам и нечего там не дергается, или вы под дерганием подразумеваете некий черный фон некоторое время после перетаскивания? Ну так этим все приложения грешат ибо вы как не крути рисуете поверх некого холста. Вот для примера запечатлел вам [Steam](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OaXs6.png), а вот новейший [GOG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQua4.jpg), как видите при ресайзе у них тоже есть проблемы с рендерингом.

Comment: GOG так и вовсе многие элементы начинает терять, а не только подложка. Единственное в чем вы правы - анимация сворачивания/разворачивания, но ее добавляет хром. К примеру я делал [такое окно](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1011208/220553) и там вроде успешно благодаря хрому отрабатывали все анимации. Так что мне все же кажется вы не о том думаете уже какой год) Но если найдете вдруг формулу окна по всем стандартам - дайте знать.

Comment: _"вы под дерганием подразумеваете некий черный фон некоторое время после перетаскивания?"_ - Нет. Это нормально. Я подразумеваю, что, например, если тянуть за левый край, правый край должен оставаться на месте, а не дёргаться с места влево, затем догоняя своё начальное положение.

Comment: _"Но если найдете вдруг формулу окна по всем стандартам - дайте знать."_ - Нашёл уже - окно Visual Studio. Вы посмотрите на него: там есть тень синего цвета, рамка изменения размера расположена на тени за пределами видимой границы окна, все анимации сворачивания/разворачивания присутствуют, нет никаких дёрганий при изменений размера.

Comment: _"правый край должен оставаться на месте, а не дёргаться с места влево, затем догоняя своё начальное положение."_ - Это и связано с тем, что старые пиксели клиентской области `BitBlt` копирует в левый верхний угол.

Comment: Мне очень интересно, почему `WindowChrome` работает [именно так](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54904747/8110665). Видимо, чтобы окно не дёргалось, нужно оставить Windows хоть немного неклиентской области. Но, опять же, у окна Visual Studio каких то таких полосок не видно, иначе бы они выходили за пределы видимой границы окна - прямо на тень.

Comment: `правый край должен оставаться на месте, а не дёргаться с места влево, затем догоняя своё начальное положение.` - этим страдают 90%, ибо как по мне это "глюк" win32 приложений. Напишите например проект на UWP, там такое вы вряд ли заметите, либо возьмите другую технологию, которая переписывает механизмы рендеринга, а не используют старые технологии. Возьмите к примеру новоиспечённый Edge от самих Microsoft на движке Chrome и потяните его за углы, увидите все те же косяки, ибо win32... Короче, я не думаю, что вы избавитесь от подобного, разрабатывая win32 приложение.

Comment: _"этим страдают 90%, ибо как по мне это "глюк" win32 приложений"_ - Я понимаю это, но если я оставлю стиль по-умолчанию, либо даже сделаю `WindowStyle="None"`, никакого такого некрасивого поведения нет. И как только сделаю необходимый мне AllowsTransparency, происходят разные непонятные вещи. Значит, должно быть какое то решение этой проблемы.

Comment: Если даже Microsoft в своих приложениях имеют такой косяк, то о каком решение идет речь? Ту же Visual Studio потяните и увидите все вышеописанное.

Comment: _"Если даже Microsoft в своих приложениях имеют такой косяк, то о каком решение идет речь?"_ - Видимо вы не понимаете что я имею ввиду. Я не могу найти ни одного приложения у себя на компьютере, которое ведёт себя не так, как я бы хотел, чтобы выглядело моё приложение. Давайте я отправлю запись с экрана.

Comment: Отправляйте, только что бы это было не стандартное окно, а полностью переписанный дизайн приложения.

Comment: Насколько мне известно, никаких квот, отводимых на рендер окна нет, а вот проблем синхронизации с монитором при отрисовке - сколько угодно. Если уж совсем закопаться в это, можно самому [через GDI](https://habr.com/ru/post/165403/) нарисовать хоть слона полупрозрачного с тенью розового цвета, будет очень быстро работать, но чтобы заниматься этим, нужна серьезная причина и конкретная цель. А копание в недостатках WPF - ну такое себе занятие, в WPF много WTF, понять и простить, спасибо что не Winforms.

Comment: @aepot под квотами на рендер здесь имеется в виду то что описано здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53000291/ Способ по вашей ссылке конечно интересен, но слишком экзотичен. Если мы пишем на WPF, хотелось бы использовать инструменты WPF, а не вручную рисовать розовых слонов на LayeredWindow. А прозрачность и быстрая отрисовка в WPF и так есть, проблемы начинаются только, когда в игру вступает DWM.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы не сможете полностью избавиться от мерцания при изменении размера из-за [ограничений DWM](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53000291/8674428) в новых версиях Windows. Собственно, наиболее известное приложение WPF, Visual Studio, тоже подвержено этой проблеме, по крайней мере по состоянию на VS 2017. Но наилучшего результата, по моим тестам, можно достичь, убрав стандартную рамку сверху с помощью обработки сообщения [WM_NCCALCSIZE](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-nccalcsize) и реализовав изменение размера через собственный обработчик WM_NCHITTEST:

```xml
<Window x:Class="WpfTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Height="250" Width="400" FontSize="14" Loaded="Window_Loaded" WindowStyle="SingleBorderWindow">

    <Grid Background="Black" x:Name="grid">

        <Button Content="Button1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="50" Margin="64,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
               Background="Green" Width="150" Click="Button1_Click" Foreground="White"/>
        <Button x:Name="bMin" Content="_" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="40" Margin="0,0,80,00" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
               Background="LightBlue" Width="40" Click="bMin_Click" />
        <Button x:Name="bMax" Content="□" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="40" Margin="0,0,40,00" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
               Background="LightBlue" Width="40" Click="bMax_Click" />
        <Button Content="X" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="40" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
               Background="Red" Width="40" Click="ButtonClose_Click" />
        <Label  Content="Label" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Margin="0,0,0,0" Foreground="White"
                   VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50" />

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Interop;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace WpfTest
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        IntPtr Handle;
        int xborder;
        int yborder;

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct RECT
        {
            public int left, top, right, bottom;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        struct NCCALCSIZE_PARAMS
        {
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 3)]
            public RECT[] rgrc;
            public IntPtr lppos;
        }

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hwnd, out RECT lpRect);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern bool AdjustWindowRectEx(ref RECT lpRect, uint dwStyle,
        bool bMenu, uint dwExStyle);

        [DllImport("dwmapi.dll")]
        static extern bool DwmDefWindowProc(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref IntPtr plResult);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern int GetSystemMetrics(uint smIndex);

        static int GET_X_LPARAM(IntPtr lp)
        {
            short loword = (short)((ulong)lp & 0xffff);
            return loword;
        }

        static int GET_Y_LPARAM(IntPtr lp)
        {
            short hiword = (short)((((ulong)lp) >> 16) & 0xffff);
            return hiword;
        }

        const uint WM_NCCALCSIZE = 0x0083;
        const uint WM_NCHITTEST = 0x0084;
        const uint WM_ACTIVATE = 0x0006;
        const uint WM_NCACTIVATE = 0x0086;
        const uint WM_NCPAINT = 0x85;

        const uint WS_OVERLAPPED = 0x00000000;
        const uint WS_CAPTION = 0x00C00000;
        const uint WS_SYSMENU = 0x00080000;
        const uint WS_THICKFRAME = 0x00040000;
        const uint WS_MINIMIZEBOX = 0x00020000;
        const uint WS_MAXIMIZEBOX = 0x00010000;
        const uint WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW = WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU |
              WS_THICKFRAME | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_MAXIMIZEBOX;

        const uint HTTOPLEFT = 13;
        const uint HTTOPRIGHT = 14;
        const uint HTTOP = 12;
        const uint HTCAPTION = 2;
        const uint HTLEFT = 10;
        const uint HTNOWHERE = 0;
        const uint HTRIGHT = 11;
        const uint HTBOTTOM = 15;
        const uint HTBOTTOMLEFT = 16;
        const uint HTBOTTOMRIGHT = 17;

        const uint SM_CXSIZEFRAME = 32;
        const uint SM_CYSIZEFRAME = 33;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        //обработка координат мыши для неклиентской области
        IntPtr HitTestNCA(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
        {
            // Get the point coordinates for the hit test.
            var ptMouse = new Point(GET_X_LPARAM(lParam), GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam));

            // Get the window rectangle.
            RECT rcWindow;
            GetWindowRect(hWnd, out rcWindow);

            // Get the frame rectangle, adjusted for the style without a caption.
            RECT rcFrame = new RECT();
            AdjustWindowRectEx(ref rcFrame, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW & ~WS_CAPTION, false, 0);

            // Determine if the hit test is for resizing. Default middle (1,1).
            ushort uRow = 1;
            ushort uCol = 1;
            bool fOnResizeBorder = false;

            // Determine if the point is at the top or bottom of the window.
            if (ptMouse.Y >= rcWindow.top && ptMouse.Y < rcWindow.top + yborder)
            {
                fOnResizeBorder = (ptMouse.Y < (rcWindow.top - rcFrame.top));
                uRow = 0;
            }
            else if (ptMouse.Y < rcWindow.bottom && ptMouse.Y >= rcWindow.bottom - yborder)
            {
                uRow = 2;
            }

            // Determine if the point is at the left or right of the window.
            if (ptMouse.X >= rcWindow.left && ptMouse.X < rcWindow.left + xborder)
            {
                uCol = 0; // left side
            }
            else if (ptMouse.X < rcWindow.right && ptMouse.X >= rcWindow.right - xborder)
            {
                uCol = 2; // right side
            }

            // Hit test (HTTOPLEFT, ... HTBOTTOMRIGHT)
            IntPtr[,] hitTests = new IntPtr[,]
            {
                { (IntPtr)HTTOPLEFT, fOnResizeBorder? (IntPtr)HTTOP : (IntPtr)HTCAPTION, (IntPtr)HTTOPRIGHT },
                { (IntPtr)HTLEFT,  (IntPtr)HTNOWHERE, (IntPtr)HTRIGHT},
                { (IntPtr)HTBOTTOMLEFT, (IntPtr)HTBOTTOM, (IntPtr)HTBOTTOMRIGHT },
            };

            return hitTests[uRow, uCol];
        }

        //обработчик сообщений для окна
        private IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
        {
            bool fCallDWP = true;
            IntPtr lRet = IntPtr.Zero;

            if (msg == WM_NCCALCSIZE)
            {
                if (wParam != (IntPtr)0)
                {
                    //убираем стандартную рамку сверху
                    lRet = IntPtr.Zero;

                    NCCALCSIZE_PARAMS pars = (NCCALCSIZE_PARAMS)Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, typeof(NCCALCSIZE_PARAMS));

                    pars.rgrc[0].top = pars.rgrc[0].top;
                    pars.rgrc[0].left = pars.rgrc[0].left + xborder;
                    pars.rgrc[0].right = pars.rgrc[0].right - xborder * 2;
                    pars.rgrc[0].bottom = pars.rgrc[0].bottom - yborder;
                    
                    Marshal.StructureToPtr(pars, lParam, false);

                    handled = true;
                    return lRet;
                }
            }

            if (msg == WM_NCACTIVATE)
            {
                lRet = (IntPtr)1;
                handled = true;
                return lRet;
            }                        

            fCallDWP = !DwmDefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam, ref lRet);

            if (msg == WM_NCHITTEST && lRet == IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                //обработка нажатий мыши
                lRet = HitTestNCA(hwnd, wParam, lParam);

                if (lRet != (IntPtr)HTNOWHERE)
                {
                    fCallDWP = false;
                }
            }

            //если сообщение не обработано, передаем базовой процедуре
            if (fCallDWP) handled = false;
            else handled = true;

            return lRet;
        }

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            WindowInteropHelper h = new WindowInteropHelper(this);
            HwndSource source = HwndSource.FromHwnd(h.Handle);
            Handle = h.Handle;
            source.AddHook(new HwndSourceHook(WndProc));//регистрируем обработчик сообщений
            xborder = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSIZEFRAME);
            yborder = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSIZEFRAME);
        }

        private void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Button 1");
        }

        private void bMin_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;
        }

        private void bMax_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.WindowState == System.Windows.WindowState.Normal) this.WindowState = System.Windows.WindowState.Maximized;
            else this.WindowState = System.Windows.WindowState.Normal;
        }

        private void ButtonClose_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Выглядит так:

[image: custom window]

Заточено под Windows 10. В Windows 7 способ тоже работает и дает неплохой результат, но стиль окна должен быть `WindowStyle="None"`. При других стилях мерцание противоположного края возвращается. В Windows 10 же при использовании стиля None исчезают анимации свертывания-развертывания, поэтому для разных версий Windows понадобится выставлять разный стиль.

Comment: При деактивации окна возвращается рамка (`InvalidateVisual` не помогает). Так же приемлимую рамку окна сделать не получится - при изменении размеров рамка дергается вместе с содержимым (если бы не это, фон окна можно было бы сделать таким же, как фон содержимого, и забыть о проблеме).

Comment: Так же, поскольку убирается стандартная рамка, пропадает стандартная анимация сворачивания/разворачивания окна Windows. А сама рамка изменения размера окна находится на видимой области окна с краю. Было бы хорошо, если бы вы подсказали способ как разместить её за видимой областью окна (как у стандартных окон) при этом не потеряв стандартные анимации сворачивания/разворачивания и оставить успех с устранением проблемы bitblt.

Comment: Если убрать вызов `DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea` стандартные анимации сворачивания/разворачивания возвращаются и при деактивации рамка не появляется.

Comment: "Рамку за видимой областью окна разместить невозможно, у стандартного окна она также внутри" - Сверху внутри, а со всех остальных сторон - выходит за пределы видимой границы окна пикселей на 5 (т.е. указатель мыши ещё не дошёл до края окна, а уже меняет вид и окно можно ресайзить).

Comment: Ещё одна вещь, которая сделала бы ресайз красивее - это небольшое отставание движения рамки от курсора. На данный момент если тянуть за левый или нижний край, то край окна не отстаёт от курсора, а новое место заполняется фоновым цветом окна. Этот эффект был бы не так заметен, если бы рамка отставала от курсора и много нового места сразу не высвобождалось бы.

Comment: "Ещё одна вещь, которая сделала бы ресайз красивее - это небольшое отставание движения рамки от курсора" - Возможно, добавить `Thread.Sleep` в обработчик `WM_SIZING`?

Comment: Вообще странно, почему перемещение края стандартной рамкой не вызывает никаких некрасивых эффектов, а использование самодельной рамки либо той, что создаётся в обработчиках WM_NCCALCSIZE и WN_NCHITTEST, приводит к появлению таковых.

Comment: То есть в итоге я бы хотел видеть такое окно, в котором копирование старых пикселей клиентской области происходит в верхний левый угол (когда приложение не укладывается в установленные временные квоты, само собой), но при этом у окна есть системная рамка, которая не отставая следует за курсором (не рамка, которую я создаю в стиле окна и которая по сути просто является корневым элементом для всех элементов окна, а именно системная).

Comment: Вот у Visual Studio например так: рамка с синей тенью двигается, а содержимое окна не успевает за ней и высвободившееся место заполняется чёрным.

Comment: @D.Stark обновил ответ. Вроде удалось совместить отсутствие мерцания, стандартную рамку по всем краям, кроме верха и анимации свертывания-развертывания.

Comment: Спасибо. Уже разобрался. Секрет в `NCCALCSIZE_PARAMS`.

Comment: Вот только не понятно как рамку окна убрать. Добиться эффекта можно если сделать окно `NoReisze`, `WindowStyle = None` (обычное окно). Но этот способ не годится.

Comment: @D.Stark полностью убрать рамку? Просто вернуть 0 из WM_NCCALCSIZE, без изменения NCCALCSIZE_PARAMS.

Comment: Я имею ввиду визуальную рамку

Comment: Хочу сделать свою другого цвета. Да и та рамка какая то странная получается - на три стороны. Видимо это связано со строчкой `pars.rgrc[0].top = pars.rgrc[0].top;`.

Comment: Если эту рамку никак не убрать, то мне нужно хотя бы выяснить в коде какого она цвета, чтобы дополнить верхнюю границу.

Comment: @D.Stark Рамка убрана только сверху намеренно, чтобы по другим сторонам сохранялось поведение "рамка изменения размера за пределами видимой области" на Windows 10. А на других ОС, где рамка видимая, это будет выглядеть странно, так что можете убрать все стороны рамки и нарисовать свою, если так будет лучше.