# Как убрать серую рамку на окне Windows 7

Tags: wpf, .net

Если установить свойство окна `WindowStyle` в значение `None` и запустить под Windows 7, то рамка изменения размера окна окрасится в серый цвет. Что нужно сделать, чтобы убрать этот эффект? Окно **должно быть** `CanResize`.

Используется .NET 4.5.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Перерисуйте окно с установкой хрома для ресайза, да и все. К примеру, как [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1011208/220553).

Comment: Использование `WindowChrome` мне не подходит, поскольку это приводит к множеству ненужных эффектов при работе с окном.

Comment: Здесь решение аналогично [этому](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1130986/240512), только нужно убрать все стороны неклиентской области, т.е. просто вернуть 0 из обработчика WM_NCCALCSIZE. Совместить решение для разных ОС не получиться, нужно иметь для каждой свою отдельную реализацию окна.

Comment: _"просто вернуть 0 из обработчика WM_NCCALCSIZE"_ - Там и так 0 возвращается. На счёт не совмещать решения для разных ОС совет полезный думаю.

Comment: Я имею в виду, что в обработчике должно быть только `handled = true;return IntPtr.Zero;`, без какого-либо другого кода, изменяющего значения NCCALCSIZE_PARAMS

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight Да, это работает на Windows 7

Comment: В Windows 8 я думаю поведение будут аналогично Windows 10

Comment: Ещё хотелось бы спросить знаете ли вы как получить значение цвета рамки окна в Windows 10 (либо убрать её): https://ibb.co/6gSqbpM (слева). Вроде уже спрашивал что то подобное.

Comment: Как получить цвет не знаю, убрать рамку слева также как и сверху, не изменять значение pars.rgrc[0].left в обработчике WM_NCCALCSIZE

Comment: Весь смысл использования обработчика пропадает, если не менять `lParam`.

Comment: _"Как получить цвет не знаю"_ - `GetSysColor(COLOR_WINDOWFRAME)`.

Comment: "*Весь смысл использования обработчика пропадает, если не менять lParam*" -  Тут сам факт обработки сообщения важен. `handled = true;` предотвращает вызов DefWndProc, который создает стандартную рамку. А менять значения lParam нужно, если мы хотим вернуть отдельные стороны этой рамки.