# Создание поведения WPF для перемещения окна без рамки

Tags: c#, wpf, behaviors

Пишу простенькое приложение WPF, решил убрать границы у окошек в оном, но столкнулся с проблемой перемещения окошка. Немного погуглив имеющиеся вопросы, я нашёл довольно простое решение:

```
bool isKeyPressed = false;

public MainWindow()
{
       InitializeComponent();
       this.PreviewKeyDown += (s1, e1) => { if (e1.Key == Key.LeftCtrl) isKeyPressed = true; };
       this.PreviewKeyUp += (s2, e2) => { if (e2.Key == Key.LeftCtrl) isKeyPressed = false; };
       this.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown += (s, e) => { if (isKeyPressed) DragMove(); };
}
```

Однако, так как у меня будет приложение с несколькими окнами, было бы удобнее использовать Behavior. Я пока не понял, как сделать проверку на нажатие LeftCtrl и само перетягиваение окна с помощью Behavior.

**Нужна помощь!** *Желательно, с пояснениями*, чтобы на будущее мог сам. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117050/discussion-on-question-by-koryjaxx---wpf).

Answer (score 0):

Не очень понятно, зачем здесь Behavior, это бесполезный механизм, который тянет за собой стороннюю библиотеку, но при этом ничего особо не дает. Скорее я бы делал тут свой класс, производный от Window. Но сделать это через поведение можно как-то так:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" WindowStyle="SingleBorderWindow" >
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>       
        <local:MyBehavior/>
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <Grid x:Name="grid" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Black">
        <Button x:Name="bMin" Content="_" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="40" Margin="0,0,80,00" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
               Background="LightBlue" Width="40" Click="bMin_Click" />
        <Button x:Name="bMax" Content="□" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="40" Margin="0,0,40,00" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
               Background="LightBlue" Width="40" Click="bMax_Click" />
        <Button Content="X" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="40" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
               Background="Red" Width="40" Click="ButtonClose_Click" />

        <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="49,45,0,0" 
                VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Background="Green"
                Foreground="White" Click="Button_Click" >
        </Button>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Interactivity;
using System.Windows.Interop;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {       
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();            
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            
        }

        private void bMin_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;
        }

        private void bMax_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.WindowState == System.Windows.WindowState.Normal) this.WindowState = System.Windows.WindowState.Maximized;
            else this.WindowState = System.Windows.WindowState.Normal;
        }

        private void ButtonClose_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

    }

    public class MyBehavior : Behavior<Window> 
    {
        IntPtr Handle;        
        int yborder = 20; //высота области для перемещения
        bool loaded = false;

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct RECT
        {
            public int left, top, right, bottom;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        struct NCCALCSIZE_PARAMS
        {
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 3)]
            public RECT[] rgrc;
            public IntPtr lppos;
        }

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hwnd, out RECT lpRect);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern bool AdjustWindowRectEx(ref RECT lpRect, uint dwStyle,
        bool bMenu, uint dwExStyle);

        [DllImport("dwmapi.dll")]
        static extern bool DwmDefWindowProc(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref IntPtr plResult);
        

        static int GET_X_LPARAM(IntPtr lp)
        {
            short loword = (short)((ulong)lp & 0xffff);
            return loword;
        }

        static int GET_Y_LPARAM(IntPtr lp)
        {
            short hiword = (short)((((ulong)lp) >> 16) & 0xffff);
            return hiword;
        }

        const uint WM_NCCALCSIZE = 0x0083;
        const uint WM_NCHITTEST = 0x0084;
        const uint WM_ACTIVATE = 0x0006;
        const uint WM_NCACTIVATE = 0x0086;
        const uint WM_NCPAINT = 0x85;

        const uint WS_OVERLAPPED = 0x00000000;
        const uint WS_CAPTION = 0x00C00000;
        const uint WS_SYSMENU = 0x00080000;
        const uint WS_THICKFRAME = 0x00040000;
        const uint WS_MINIMIZEBOX = 0x00020000;
        const uint WS_MAXIMIZEBOX = 0x00010000;
        const uint WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW = WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU |
              WS_THICKFRAME | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_MAXIMIZEBOX;

        const uint HTTOPLEFT = 13;
        const uint HTTOPRIGHT = 14;
        const uint HTTOP = 12;
        const uint HTCAPTION = 2;
        const uint HTLEFT = 10;
        const uint HTNOWHERE = 0;
        const uint HTRIGHT = 11;
        const uint HTBOTTOM = 15;
        const uint HTBOTTOMLEFT = 16;
        const uint HTBOTTOMRIGHT = 17;

        const uint SM_CXSIZEFRAME = 32;
        const uint SM_CYSIZEFRAME = 33;

        //обработка координат мыши для неклиентской области
        IntPtr HitTestNCA(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
        {
            // Get the point coordinates for the hit test.
            var ptMouse = new Point(GET_X_LPARAM(lParam), GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam));

            // Get the window rectangle.
            RECT rcWindow;
            GetWindowRect(hWnd, out rcWindow);

            // Get the frame rectangle, adjusted for the style without a caption.
            RECT rcFrame = new RECT();
            AdjustWindowRectEx(ref rcFrame, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW & ~WS_CAPTION, false, 0);

            // Determine if the hit test is for resizing. Default middle (1,1).
            ushort uRow = 1;
            ushort uCol = 1;
            bool fOnResizeBorder = false;

            // Determine if the point is at the top or bottom of the window.
            if (ptMouse.Y >= rcWindow.top && ptMouse.Y < rcWindow.top + yborder)
            {
                uRow = 0;
            }

            // Hit test (HTTOPLEFT, ... HTBOTTOMRIGHT)
            IntPtr[,] hitTests = new IntPtr[,]
            {
                { (IntPtr)HTTOPLEFT, fOnResizeBorder? (IntPtr)HTTOP : (IntPtr)HTCAPTION, (IntPtr)HTTOPRIGHT },
                { (IntPtr)HTLEFT,  (IntPtr)HTNOWHERE, (IntPtr)HTRIGHT},
                { (IntPtr)HTBOTTOMLEFT, (IntPtr)HTBOTTOM, (IntPtr)HTBOTTOMRIGHT },
            };

            return hitTests[uRow, uCol];
        }

        //обработчик сообщений для окна
        private IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
        {
            bool fCallDWP = true;
            IntPtr lRet = IntPtr.Zero;

            if (msg == WM_NCCALCSIZE)
            {
                if (wParam != (IntPtr)0)
                {
                    //убираем стандартную рамку
                    lRet = IntPtr.Zero;
                    handled = true;
                    return lRet;
                }
            }

            if (msg == WM_NCACTIVATE)
            {
                lRet = (IntPtr)1;
                handled = true;
                return lRet;
            }

            fCallDWP = !DwmDefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam, ref lRet);

            if (msg == WM_NCHITTEST && lRet == IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                //обработка нажатий мыши
                lRet = HitTestNCA(hwnd, wParam, lParam);

                if (lRet != (IntPtr)HTNOWHERE)
                {
                    fCallDWP = false;
                }
            }

            //если сообщение не обработано, передаем базовой процедуре
            if (fCallDWP) handled = false;
            else handled = true;

            return lRet;
        }

        void Load(HwndSource source)
        {
            if (loaded) return;

            Handle = source.Handle;
            source.AddHook(new HwndSourceHook(WndProc));//регистрируем обработчик сообщений
            loaded = true;
        }

        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            base.OnAttached();
            HwndSource hwndSource = (HwndSource)HwndSource.FromVisual(AssociatedObject);

            if (hwndSource == null)
            {
                AssociatedObject.SourceInitialized += OnSourceInitialized;
                return;
            }

            Load(hwndSource);
        }

        void OnSourceInitialized(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HwndSource hwndSource = (HwndSource)HwndSource.FromVisual(AssociatedObject);

            if (hwndSource == null)
            {
                WindowInteropHelper h = new WindowInteropHelper(AssociatedObject);
                hwndSource = HwndSource.FromHwnd(h.Handle);
            }

            Load(hwndSource);
        }
    }
}
```

Здесь убирается стандартная рамка с помощью обработки WM_NCCALCSIZE и восстанавливается возможность перемещения окна перетаскиванием за область высотой в 20 пикселей в верхней части (модификация способа из https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1130986/240512).