# Перемещение окна WPF мышкой

Tags: c#, wpf

Значит, нашёл я как перемещать мышкой WinForms окно, а как WPF не нашёл

Окно полностью состоит из своих элементов, а двигать хочется за лейбл(так скажем "шапка")

Может кто-то знает?

код:

```
private void headlbl_MouseMove(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (isMouseDown)
    {
        this.Margin = new Thickness(System.Windows.Forms.Control.MousePosition.X, System.Windows.Forms.Control.MousePosition.Y, 0, 0);
    }
}

private void headlbl_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    isMouseDown = true;
}

private void headlbl_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    isMouseDown = false;
}
```

Comment: Точно также перемещать

Comment: не выходит, говорит что нет перегруженного метода

Comment: вам ответят, если конкретизируете вопрос. двигать мышкой или кодом? возможно выставили у окна какое-то блокирующее свойство (как вы создаете окно?). вот [пример1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545258/changing-the-start-up-location-of-a-wpf-window) и [пример2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16608523/c-sharp-wpf-move-the-window) правильно заданных вопросов. возможно из ответов вы что-то почерпнете для себя.

Comment: Ну то есть вы что то где то сделали, у вас что то где то не получилось. Из этого ни ваша проблема не ясна, ни ваш код не видно.

Comment: какой код предоставить?
проблема в том, что я не знаю как двигать WPF окно курсором за лейбл.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В вашем вопросе есть ряд ошибок, которые я советую вам исправить сразу.

1. `Label` - в WPF проекте это не очень хороший контрол для вывода текста. Дело тут в том, что `Label`, это `ContentControl`, то есть элемент, который предназначен для вывода всего, даже если это не является текстом (например, `<Label><Button Content = "Привет мир!"/></Label>`). Зачастую эта "перегруженность" бывает лишней, ведь нам нужно лишь вывести текст. Поэтому, советую забыть про `Label` и использовать `TextBlock`, который предназначен именно для текста.
2. `this.Margin` - я надеюсь вы не используете такое в WPF? Если используете, то это очень плохо, ведь в WPF проекте есть 2 базовые вещи, на котором стоится весь проект, а именно `XAML` и `Binding`, и если вы ими пренебрегаете, то смысл вообще в WPF? Не используйте контролы в коде, создавайте их в XAML, делайте им нужное поведение и стили там! Также не используйте контролы как источник данных (`tb.Text = "Привет мир!"`), это повлечет за собой много проблем в дальнейшем (включая производительность), лучше задайте окну `DataContext` на некий класс, в котором будет простое свойство (`public string Text { get; set; }`) и в XAML привяжите его (`<TextBlock Text = "{Binding Text}"/>`), все, вы отвязали данные от контролов, теперь просто работайте со свойствами и классами, не затрагивая UI.

**Теперь про перетаскивание**

- Если вам надо перетаскивать окно зажатием мыши по конкретному элементу (что странно), то для этого у окна есть специальный метод, `DragMove()`, который достаточно вызвать при вызове события `MouseDown` контрола. То есть, самое элементарное, это

  XAML:

  ```
  <Label MouseDown="Label_MouseDown" Content="Привет мир!"/>
  ```

  C#:

  ```
  private void Label_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) => DragMove();
  ```

  Все, теперь при зажатии мыши на `Label` у вас будет двигаться окно.
- Если вы делаете "шапку", то значит вам надо просто вернуть стандартное поведение, а не вешать события на контролы. Для этого, достаточно окну задать `WindowChrome`

  XAML:

  ```
  <Window ....>
    <WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
        <WindowChrome/>
    </WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
  </Window>
  ```

  Все, у вашего окна полностью восстановлено стандартное поведение "шапки", включая перетаскивание, меню на ПКМ, растягивание и прочее. Все размеры и др. можете настроить самостоятельно у объекта `<WindowChrome/>`. У вас кстати может возникнуть одна проблема - не проходит клик по объекту (к примеру кнопка), которая находится в области хрома. Решение простое: задать `WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome="True"`. Пример этого всего можете глянуть [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1011208/220553).

Вообще, "кастомное" окно, это весьма сложная вещь, там сложно сделать все правильно, везде есть свои "НО". Я уверен, что сейчас вы сделали `WindowStyle="None" AllowsTransparency="True"`, поверх накидали контролов и радуетесь. Ок, в чем недостаток? А в том, что вы потеряли при таком подходе к примеру анимацию сворачивания окна, которую делает Windows. Решением будет [такой подход](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1130986/220553), который тоже не без греха.

Короче, предоставил вам вроде все необходимое, дерзайте)