# Плавная анимация окна программы при WindowStyle="none"

Tags: c#, wpf, анимация

Всем привет. Хотел спросить, как можно сделать анимацию появления программы. То есть, если программу запускать со свойством `WindowStyle="SingleBorderWindow"`, то программа плавно появляется, изменяется прозрачность при появлении и само окно словно меняет размер (пример показан ниже). Но если использовать `WindowStyle="none"`, то при запуске программы никакой анимации нет, программа сразу же показывается, при сворачивании резко исчезает, ну и когда закрываешь программу, то она тоже резко закрывается. Как я могу реализовать подобную анимацию, но без использования `WindowStyle="SingleBorderWindow"`?

[image: Пример анимации программы при WindowStyle="SingleBorderWindow"]

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1130986/220553

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, спасибо большое!