# WPF: Размеры формы в Maximized состоянии

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-n-drop

**Дано:**
Форма без стандартной верхней рамки с тремя кнопками, т.е. `WindowStyle = None`. Но со своей.
С помощью `DragMove()`, `WindowState.Maxmimized` и `.Normal` настроено перетаскивание и изменение состояния. Также, если окно(форма) перетаскивается мышью к верхней границе экрана, то оно максимизируется (и наоборот).
**Цель:**
Перетаскивая мышью Maximized-окно, оно должно становиться `Normal` **и при этом его позиция становиться под указателем.** (Для этого используется формула. В ней нужны размеры окна в `Normal` и `Maximized` состояниях.)
**И вот проблема:**
Если максимизация была включена на кнопку, то всё ок. Если же максимизация включена путем перетаскивания окна на верхнюю границу экрана, то окно максимизируется, `state` меняется, но **изменения размера окна не фиксируются программой**. Если запросить размеры окна, то они будут как у `Normal`, хотя при этом окно Maximized. Какая-то ошибка самой винды(10) может или еще что...

**Скажите как решить эту проблему правильно?**

P.S. Я новичок в программировании.

Comment: А зачем все это, если можно просто переписать хром окна?

Comment: О чем вы?  Браузер?

Comment: Кажется, вы перемудрили. Это всё можно сделать без единой строчки кода. Но начните с того, чтобы показать воспроизводимый пример.

Comment: Ну [вот например](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1011208/220553), обратите внимание на `WindowChrome`, который возвращает кастомному окну опции перетаскивания, изменения размеров и так далее.