# wpf растягивание окна влево или вправо за левую сторону рамки

Tags: c#, wpf

Как можно растянуть окно влево или вправо за левую сторону рамки ?

Так возникают проблемы с окном

```
double newWidth = e.GetPosition(this).X;
 this.Left = newWidth;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Почему только "влево"? Если вам надо растягиваемое окно, то переопределите хром.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ можно и в влево и в право

Comment: Ну тогда почему не хром? Зачем вы пишете костыли для того, что и так есть из коробки?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ какой хром ?

Comment: [WindowChrome](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.shell.windowchrome?view=net-5.0). Просто пишете у окна `<WindowChrome.WindowChrome><WindowChrome/></WindowChrome.WindowChrome>` и все, у вас окно, которое можно двигать за верх и изменять размер за края. Вот даже вам [пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1011208/220553) подобного.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ спасибо большое

Comment: @EvgeniyZ почему в том примере кнопки не работают ? и при наведении на кнопку цвета не меняются. Я создал новый проект для этого примера. Хоть и параметр включен как я вижу  WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome="True"

Comment: Наверно потому, что их функционал там не реализован? Если вас смутила фраза "ну и работают все кнопки", то это ответ на "я не могу изменять размер окна из-за кнопок". `WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome="True"` - это не то о чем вы подумали. Когда вы восстанавливаете хром, это если грубо объяснять, представьте слои, вот поверх вашего основного слоя, накладывается дополнительный, прозрачный слой, который имеет края (рамку) и верх (шапку), если например за "шапкой" будет кнопка, то без указания `IsHitTestVisibleInChrome` она будет некликабельна, ибо клик будет идти по "шапке", а не кнопке.

Comment: Функционал кнопок (закрытие, сворачивание, разворачивание), вам надо делать самостоятельно, ну и `при наведении на кнопку цвета не меняются` тоже на вас, это стиль. В том примере я лишь быстро набросал кастомное окно, не более.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ спасибо за уточнение