# Белая полоса наверху окна WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Делаю приложение WPF, убрал WindowStyle у окна, ResizeMode стоит CanResize.
Если стоит CanResize, то у меня почему-то появляется такая белая полоса сверху (в не полном окне):
[image: Скрин приложения]

Если я ставлю NoResize, то эта полоса убирается, но экран ,соответственно, увеличивать/уменьшать я не могу. Не понимаю, что за полоса и как её убрать

Comment: [Оставлю тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1011208/220553)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это граница изменения размера. Вы можете удалить ее и сделать окно изменяемым `ResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip" AllowsTransparency="True"`

```
<Window x:Class="HandsOnSolution.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" 
        Background="Green" WindowStyle="None"
        ResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip" AllowsTransparency="True">
    <Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Если вас интересует перетаскивание, то можно сделать такой обработчик события:

```
<Window MouseLeftButtonDown="Window_MouseLeftButtonDown"/>

//code behind
private void Window_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    DragMove();
}
```

Ответ взят отсюда: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36631165/how-to-remove-white-strip-on-top-of-wpf-window-with-windowstyle-none