# Не убирается полностью заголовок окна при windowstyle none

Tags: c#, wpf

Не убирается полностью заголовок окна при windowstyle none. В конструкторе эта полоса не отображается,  [image: наглядно видно что в конструкторе всё нормально]

однако после компиляции появляется полоса.
[image: видна полоса после компиляции]

Разметка окна имеет следующий вид:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы имеете дело с границей изменения размера окна. Вот тут есть подробный ответ, как быть в такой ситуации: [Белая полоса наверху окна WPF](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1283278)

Если коротко, то нужно выставить `ResizeMode="NoResize"`

Comment: Благодарю, вы полностью ответили на мой вопрос.