# Как применить особенности стандартного window заголовка

Tags: wpf, xaml

Начнём с того что я снёс обычный заголовок окна (WindowStyle="None"), вместо него в первом гридроу (который нулевой) расположил border (пусть он будет borderMain) в котором находится stackpanel, в свою очередь она содержит кнопки закрытия, минимизации и максимизации окна.
Сам window я сделал прозрачным и в качестве него выступает border на котором всё и находится (благодаря гриду) это сделано для закруглённых углов.
Кнопки работают, перетаскивание окна за borderMain тоже, хочется сделать что бы при его перемещении в верхнюю точку экрана оно максимизировалось WindowState="Maximized" (ровно как это происходит с обычными окнами в винде). Ну и обратное действие, хватаешь за этот же borderMain (который на данный момент раскрыт во весь экран) тащишь и оно принимает значение WindowState="Normal".
Последнее я реализовал, основную задачу оно выполняет (переводит окно в Normal), но окно берёт прошлое своё положение, по итогу я двигаю курсором по воздуху (ага), а окно на некотором расстоянии так же передвигается.

Comment: Вы делаете много лишнего! Задайте хром окну, он вернет вам и изменение размера за края, и изменение состояния окна, и даже перетаскивание за "шапку".

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Кнопки и перетаскивание за шапку у меня работают. Делаю это вручную, потому как моей программе не подходит стандартная шапка по визуалу.
Мне же нужно реализовать некоторые фишки, что бы было максимально похоже оп функционалу на стандартную шапку (например перевезти окно из максимального режима окна в нормальное просто потащив за шапку, при этом что бы окно сохранило своё положение относительно курсора (у каждого это работает)).

Comment: Вы вместо того, чтобы спорить, услышали бы то, что я вам говорю, а говорю я вам "Вы делаете уйму лишнего, это делается в пару строк XAML кода, зовется это ХРОМ". [Гляньте это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1011208/220553).