# Пользовательский заголовок при использовании нескольких мониторов. Определение абсолютных координат курсора мыши

Tags: c#, wpf, мышь

Суть проблемы : у WPF окна кастомный header вместо стандартного.

```
<Window ...
        WindowStyle="None"/>    
    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                <RowDefinition/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid MouseLeftButtonDown="DragMove_MouseLeftButtonDown"                   
                  x:Name="HeaderGrid">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
        <TextBlock></TextBlock>
        <Button x:Name="btnMinimize" Content="" Style="{StaticResource HeaderButton}"
               
                
                Click="btnMinimize_Click"
                />
        <Button x:Name="btnMaximize" Content="" Style="{StaticResource HeaderButton}"
                
                
                Click="btnMaximize_Click"
                />
        <Button x:Name="btnClose" Content="❌" Style="{StaticResource HeaderButton}"
                FontWeight="Light"
                FontSize="16"
                Click="btnClose_Click"
                Margin="0 0 5 0"
                />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Нужно воспроизвести поведение стандартного заголовка окна. То есть, что бы можно было за него перетаскивать, а так же, в случае, когда окно развёрнуто, то нажав на него, оно возвращается к обычному размеру и позиционируется под курсором мышки.
С одним монитором всё работает отлично

```
        private void DragMove_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            if (WindowState == WindowState.Maximized)
            {
                WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
                System.Windows.Point mousePosition = Mouse.GetPosition(this);
                Top = mousePosition.Y;
                Left = mousePosition.X - (Width / 2) + (1920 * GetCurrentScreenNumber());
            }
            DragMove();
        }
        
        public int GetCurrentScreenNumber()
        {
            System.Drawing.Point cursorPosition = System.Windows.Forms.Control.MousePosition;
            Screen screen = Screen.FromPoint(cursorPosition);
            return Array.IndexOf(Screen.AllScreens, screen);
        }
```

С двумя всё уже гораздо сложнее с таким подходом. Пока смог реализовать относительно корректную работу двух дисплеев в случае, когда основной находится слева.

Но что если экранов 3 или больше?
Есть ли какой-то вариант определять координаты курсора не в относительных текущего экрана координатах, а в абсолютных? Ведь приведённый пример вполне себе работает, а значит есть какая-то абсолютная сетка экранных координат? Как-то можно получать координаты с неё? Или есть какие-то ещё пути решения данной проблемы?

П.С.: в WPF, я так понимаю своих механизмов получить координаты мыши нет и их приходится тащить из Winforms?

Comment: Стандартное поведение - это `WindowChrome`, вам достаточно его восстановить, не более.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ да, я сейчас наткнулся на такое решение.
 https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1011188/Граница-с-эффектом-у-окна-c-wpf/1011208#1011208 - но в нём нажатие кнопок не срабатывает почему-то у Header, хотя они там есть и к ним привязан обработчик. Нужно настроить перехват нажатия у WindowChrome?

Comment: Внимание на `WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome`

Comment: @EvgeniyZ большое вам спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Благодаря подсказкам @EvgeniyZ удалось реализовать нужное поведение с использованием класса WindowChrome.
Для возможности клика по кнопкам в заголовке, используется свойство кнопок WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome="True"
Работает с любым количеством и расположением мониторов. Позволяет создавать полностью настроенный под себя заголовок, например для ночной темы.

```
<Window x:Class="TestProject.View.TestWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d" 
        WindowStyle="None" AllowsTransparency="True"
        Background="Transparent"
        Height="450" Width="800">
    <WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
        <WindowChrome ResizeBorderThickness="7"/>
    </WindowChrome.WindowChrome>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
            <Button Content=""
                            WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome="True"                            
                            Click="btnMinimize_Click"
                            />
            <Button Content=""
                            WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome="True"                            
                            Click="btnMaximize_Click"
                            />
            <Button Content="❌"
                            WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome="True"
                            FontWeight="Light"
                            FontSize="16"
                            Click="btnClose_Click"
                            Margin="0 0 5 0"
                            />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Код методов кнопок заголовка :

```
        private void btnClose_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Close();
        }

        private void btnMaximize_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (WindowState == WindowState.Maximized)
            {
                WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
            }
            else
            {
                WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
            }
        }

        private void btnMinimize_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;
        }
```